# Submitting a search is not sending me to the page specified in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to submit a search which should redirect me to the page that I want on submission. However, submitting the form just redirects me to the index page.

```
<form class="searchbox" onsubmit="gotToCorrectSearchPage();" ><input id="tags" type="search" placeholder="Search"/></form>
```

The Javascript function, `goToCorrectSearchPage`, which is called `onsubmit`, is below. The alert works, but then I am redirected to the index page. Note: `goToSearchPage` is a variable that has been set somewhere else. If I simply call `window.location=goToSearchPage;` in the javascript console it takes me to the correct page.

```
function gotToCorrectSearchPage() {
    alert("directing you");
    window.location=goToSearchPage;
}
```

Thus, I need a way to call this `window.location=goToSearchPage;` correctly inside of the `goToCorrectSearchPage` function such that it will load the page saved in the `goToSearchPage` variable, and not load index page. I have tried a number of default action preventions on the form inside of the `goToCorrectSearchPage` function, but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly can't you use the form's action? If it's because you want it to go to whatever is in that variable, why not set the form's action attribute instead of defining that variable?

Comment: @KevinB for some reason I don't think I can set the form action attribute to a variable. I tried setting it to `action='goToSearchPage`

Comment: `$("#theform").attr("action",somevariable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is submitting and refreshing the page. You need to cancel it.

```
onsubmit="gotToCorrectSearchPage(); return false"
```

Ideally you would use preventDefault or set the action and let the form do its thing.